# Count the number of cities visited in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data table that contains two variables, the first column contains a number of cities a person visited and the other one is the rating of the trip, example as code below:

```
trips <- data.frame(
  Cities_Visitted=c("New York/San Diego","Chicago/New York","Chicago/New 
                    York/Los Angeles"),
  Trip_Rating=c(6,8,3))
```

and i have another vector that contains a full list of cities, as below:

```
city_list <- c("New York","Chicago","Los Angeles","Houston","San Diego")
```

What i want to achieve is to add a new column to the trips data frame that indicates the number of cities in the city_list are included in each trip, the result would be like this:

```
               Cities_Visitted Trip_Rating Total_Number_Cities
           New York/San Diego           6                   2
             Chicago/New York           8                   2
 Chicago/New York/Los Angeles           3                   3
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in R?

Answer (score 2):

A simple straight forward answer from stringr package

```
library(stringr)
trips$Total_Number_Cities <- str_count(trips$Cities_Visitted, '/') + 1
```

this will give you required output. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Hunaidkhan, thanks for your help. But the Cities_Visitted column contains other information and cities may be separted by different symbols other than "/", any other ideas?

Comment: you can use "OR" condition  in the str_count condition